# Python - Parsing Excel files / Differences between xlrd and openpyxl (date system and cell value types)

Tags: python, openpyxl, xlrd

Due to the fact that xlrd has deprecated parsing of xlsx files, I am being forced to migrate my excel file parser from xlrd to openpyxl.

As of now, I am finding it unclear as to how I would be able to determine the date system format, as well as determine a given cell value's data type using openpyxl.

I would like to know the equivalent way of obtaining these values in openpyxl vs xlrd.

For example, I can see that:

Getting a workbook's date system in xlrd is done with **book.datemode**

Getting a cell value's data type in xlrd is done with
**cell.ctype == xlrd.XL_CELL_EMPTY/XL_CELL_TEXT/XL_CELL_NUMBER** and so on

I've been reviewing the openpyxl docs [here](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/) without much luck on how to do what I want to do, for now.

Here's my code so far:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from ext.falcon.errors import HTTPError

book = load_workbook(self._file.read())
sheet = book.active
for row in range(sheet.rows):
        rows.append(pythonize_xl_row(sheet.row(row), book.datemode)) # date system issue

def pythonize_xl_row(row, datemode):
    result = []
    for i, cell in enumerate(row):
        if cell.ctype in [xlrd.XL_CELL_EMPTY, xlrd.XL_CELL_BLANK]: # cell value issue
            value = ""
        elif cell.ctype == xlrd.XL_CELL_TEXT: # cell value issue
            value = cell.value.strip()
        elif cell.ctype == xlrd.XL_CELL_NUMBER: # cell value issue
            value = str(cell.value)
            if value.endswith(".0"):
                value = str(int(cell.value))
        elif cell.ctype == xlrd.XL_CELL_DATE: # cell value issue
            value = xlrd.xldate.xldate_as_datetime(cell.value, datemode).strftime(
                "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
            )
        elif cell.ctype == xlrd.XL_CELL_BOOLEAN: # cell value issue
            value = str(cell.value == 1)
        else:
            raise HTTPError(
                400, "Invalid cell type at row {}: {}".format(i, cell.ctype)
            )
        result.append(value)
    return result
```

Thank you!

Comment: openpyxl handles the conversion to Python for you.

Comment: @CharlieClark can you elaborate? I went through the openpyxl docs head to toe yesterday and I'm not sure what you mean! Thanks